# JBoss AS7 mod_proxy or mod_cluster or mod_jk

Tags: apache-2.2, tomcat, mod-proxy, jboss

JBoss AS7 mod_proxy or mod_cluster

Let me begin a cluster of JBoss AS7 servers. I have discovered that it might be done using apache with mod_proxy or with mod_cluster. Which can you use? Which is simpler to determine and maintain? Which supplies better performance?

Answer (score 1):

Definitely mod_cluster. mod_cluster, among other features...

- advertises its presence via multicast so as workers can join without any configuration
- workers will report their available contexts
- mod_cluster will create proxies for these contexts automatically
- if you want to, you can still fine-tune this behaviour, e.g. so as .gif images are served from httpd and not from workers...
- most importantly: unlike pure mod_proxy or mod_jk, mod_cluster knows exactly how much load there is on each node because nodes are reporting their load back to the balancer via special messages
- default communication goes over AJP, you can use HTTP and HTTPS

I feel like a sales guy now :-D OMG

Take a look: http://www.jboss.org/mod_cluster
Grab the sources: https://github.com/modcluster/mod_cluster/